# Using 32-bit drivers on a 64-bit operating system

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 64-bit, 32-bit

Can I use the 32 bits version of my drivers on a Windows 7 x64 machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot. You will need to find 64-bit drivers for your devices. From [Microsoft's FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/32-bit-and-64-bit-Windows-frequently-asked-questions):

> **If I'm running a 64-bit version of
>   Windows, do I need 64-bit drivers for
>   my devices?**
>
> Yes. All hardware devices need 64-bit
>   drivers to work on a 64-bit version of
>   Windows. Drivers designed for 32-bit
>   versions of Windows don't work on
>   computers running 64-bit versions of
>   Windows.
>
> To learn how to check for drivers, see
>   [Update a driver for hardware that
>   isn't working properly](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Update-a-driver-for-hardware-that-isnt-working-properly) or go to the
>   device manufacturer's website. You can
>   also get information about drivers by
>   going to the [Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=140296)
>   webpage.